# Datatables - Referencing columns within a subobject

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm attempting to create a datatable, where the supplied Data has subobjects which I need to use for the columns.

Example data:

```
data: {
    player: {
        name: 'Sir Testington',
        outfit: 'Blah Outfit'
    },
    metrics: {
        kills: 123,
        deaths: 123
    }
}
```

Example datatable code:

```
$('#playerLeaderboard').DataTable({
    data: $scope.alert.metrics.players.data,
    columns: [
        { data: player.name }, // Fails here, not able to reference subobjects
        { data: player.outfit },
        { data: metrics.kills },
        { data: metrics.deaths }
    ]
});
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: do you have any console error?

Comment: An alert fires that says datatables couldn't find the column.

Comment: you have `player` and `metrics` into data, for reference you should use `data.player.name` and the data should be so `data={ player: { name: 'Sir Testington', outfit: 'Blah Outfit' }, metrics: { kills: 123, deaths: 123
}}`

Comment: Tred that before asking the question, didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `data` literal (or JSON) *must* be an array of something. That could be an array of arrays, an array of nested items or whatever. Your data literal should have a structure like this :

```
var data = [
   { player: {...}, metrics: {...} },
   { player: {...}, metrics: {...} },     
   ...
]
```

Then, if you reference to nested items within a `data` item, reference them as strings :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  data : data,
  columns: [
        { data: 'player.name' }, // Fails here, not able to reference subobjects
        { data: 'player.outfit' },
        { data: 'metrics.kills' },
        { data: 'metrics.deaths' }
    ]
})
```

You cannot make references to variables or objects that does not exist (`player.outfit` does not exists) - but dataTables can easily figure out you are referencing nested items if you pass a *path* to that item, like `'player.outfit'`. See your code working here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/xsjkegL9/**